# Jdbc request parameters are not passed to the h2 database

Tags: spring, h2, spring-jdbc

Runtime environment: java-17-spring-jdbc

Maven dependencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The parameters are passed like this:

```
sql = "select * from storedProc(:param0, :param1, :param2)"
paramsQuery = {param0=palomnic, param1=20220515, param2=20220515}
```

Request execution:

```
List<T> jdbc.query(String sql, Map<String, Object> paramsQuery, RowMapper<T> rowMapper);
```

for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

The error occurs in the body of the procedure `storedProc` db h2
it is reported that all parameters = null

The same code is executed without errors when connecting to db postgresql

How to correctly pass parameters for db h2 ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the error occurs in the body of the procedure storedProc db h2 it is reported that all parameters = null

text error:
[500] Internal Server Error

PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [call actorProtocolRangeDate(?, ?, ?);]; Ошибка преобразования данных при конвертации "null" Data conversion error converting "null"; ... [22018-212]

in the console, the request is executed without errors.

Comment: @chronos Have you solved the issue